# Requests to ElasticSearch server return always a SSL certification error

Tags: elasticsearch

I've tried applying some of the following SO answers to an ES server:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364670/how-to-check-elasticsearch-cluster-health)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46304230/3482266)

However, I always get a SSL certificate authentication error.

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ElasticSearch for local purpose and **do not worry** about security issues, you could disable security settings as it described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html).

For example, for Linux you could change every configuration with "security" word from `true` to `false` in the elasticsearch configuration file: `elasticsearch-8.2.0/config/elasticsearch.yml`

Hope this helps!